# Autocomplete with Django + React

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I'm creating a web app using Django Rest Framework for the backend and will use React for the frontend. I'd like to create a field where the user can enter the university they attend and want that to be a drop down/autocomplete search option (ex: user types in "U" then "UC Berkeley" and "UC Los Angeles" show up). I have a CSV file with all the college data, and I'd like the search to autocomplete from there. I've found this resource (here: https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html) in other Stack Overflow posts, but nothing of how to import from the CSV file.

Are there any resources for this? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!